# How display the name of an object in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

For example, if I attributed a value to an object:

```
pos1=[3,2];
```

And then, I attributed these value to the variable 'target_position':

```
target_position=pos1;
```

How can I call the 'target_position' variable and display either its name or its value? like this:

```
>> target_position

target_position =

     3     2
```

Or

```
>> target_position

target_position =

     'pos1'
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because I would like to call either the name or the value in a script.

Comment: You can use a struct e.g. `target_position.name = 'pos1';`  `target_position.value = pos1` or a cell array. But I really doubt if you *really* need to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I have several positions and I would like to attribute one position to a target stimulus within a loop, and attribute the other positions randomly to distractor stimuli. And for that I need to remove the 'pos1' to the possible positions for the distractors. To do that, I need to call either the name or the value of the available positions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not an expert in Matlab, so maybe I don't need to do it, but with the script that I wrote, it seems necessary...

Comment: I have an error using you command: 'Field assignment to a non-structure array object. EDITS: sorry, it works, I just forgot to start with target_position = []

Comment: We'd need to see more of your code. I suspect there's a `pos2`, and possibly a `pos3`, in which case you should instead have an array of positions `pos(n,2)`. Then `target_position` would hold the row index into `pos` (`pos(1,:)`, `pos(2,:)`, etc) and `pos(target_position, :)` would give you the position (i.e. `[3, 2]`).